# How to indicate if there is more text to scroll down to using UITextView in iOS?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, scroll, uitextview

Specifically, I want an image to pop up for a few seconds if there is more text to scroll down to. The image popping up is not a problem but I can't see how to set up the scrolling delegate and work out how much text is left.

Answer (score 4):

set the delegate property for UItextview

```
textview.delegate = self;
[textview flashScrollIndicators];
```

It will flash an indicator to show more text is available.

Comment: Thanks. That wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it serves the purpose.